# Define and initialize an array of strings in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

Im trying to define and initialize an array of strings using a function, but, the function is causing segmentation fault while allocating memory for each of the pointers.

Please find below the minimal reproducible version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COL     100
#define ROW     10

int init_arr(char ***arr_ptr) {
    *arr_ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * ROW);

    for(int temp_iter = 0; temp_iter < ROW; ++temp_iter) {
        *arr_ptr[temp_iter] = malloc(COL + 1);
        strncpy(*arr_ptr[temp_iter], "MY_STRING_IS_THIS", COL);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char **arr_of_str = NULL;
    init_arr(&arr_of_str);

    for(int temp_iter = 0; temp_iter < ROW; ++temp_iter) {
        printf("\nData: %s", arr_of_str[temp_iter]);
    }
}
```

This code works fine when the function is split into 2 where the first function defines it and 2nd one initializes it.

Comment: It's a matter of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Also be careful when using [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), there's a case where it will not add the null-terminator.

Comment: The true reason for the bug is "three star programming". Could have been avoided with `char** init arr(void);`, since you apparently don't do any error handling anyway.

Comment: Lastly, please make it a habit to print a *trailing* newline with `printf`, not leading. The reason is that `stdout` (where `printf` writes) is by default *line buffered*, so a newline flushes (and actually writes) the string. With a leading newline you flush and print the *previous* line, not the current string you print.

Comment: `*arr_ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * ROW);` allocates space for ROW char *s.  It is extremely likely that `sizeof(char *)` is exactly the same as `sizeof(char **)`, but why not make it robust( and easier on the reader) by writing `*arr_ptr = malloc(ROW * sizeof **arr_ptr)`.

Comment: This is all a lot cleaner if you use the normal idiom: `char **p = *arr_of_str = malloc(ROW * sizeof *p); ...; for( ; p < arr_of_str + ROW; p++) { *p = malloc ...`  Using `[]` notation is prone to error and ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here `*arr_ptr[temp_iter]`, first dereference(in his case a subscription) that was applied was from box brackets, and then from asterix. What you want to do is separate these dereferences, so that asterix is applied first and the from box brackets, like this:

```
int init_arr(char*** arr_ptr) {
    *arr_ptr = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char *) * ROW);

    for(int temp_iter = 0; temp_iter < ROW; ++temp_iter) {
        (*arr_ptr)[temp_iter] = (char*) malloc(COL + 1);
        strncpy((*arr_ptr)[temp_iter], "MY_STRING_IS_THIS", COL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, you need to cast the pointer from malloc into appropriate one, since the malloc always returns void*, and you are dereferencing void pointer later on.